# i want to delete edge (connector) from vertices which are seleted. i am using mxgraph

Tags: jgraphx

i want to delete edge which is actually connector between veritce of two shapes. i want to delete connector between the vertices which are selected by click a button.
i have used this code but it does not give me help.

```
 graph.getModel().beginUpdate();
 try {
   graph.getModel().remove( edge);
} finally {
   graph.getModel().endUpdate();
}
```

i have much study the answer of 
http://forum.jgraph.com/questions/4744/delete-edge
this question but it does not give us any help.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

```java
JButton b1 = new JButton ("Clear");
b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    // cell = component.getCellAt(e.getX(), e.getY());

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
        graph.selectChildCell();
        graph.removeCells();
    }
});
```

Comment: Try to avoid all-code answers, explain what you are doing in your code instead of just posting it.